# Javascript change the value of my object by clicking my button, but when clicked again, it doesn't switch back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, onclick

I've set up an if | else if script to switch the temperature displayed on my project from Celcius to Ferinheit, and it works. When I click the "C" It does the conversion of numbers and appends "F" to the end. However, now when I click the "F", it does not switch back, and I can't figure out why. I tried declaring the variables outside of the function in case they were getting overwritten somehow but that didn't work either. Here's the JS code (at least the piece that's relevant to the problem):

```
        num = Math.round(parseInt(arr.main.temp));
        var temp = num+String.fromCharCode(176)+`<span class=\"temp\" id='ctof'>${tempValue}</span>`; 
        $("#temperature").html(temp)
        $('#ctof').click(function () {
          var currentTempUnit = tempValue;
          var newTempUnit = currentTempUnit == "C" ? "F" : "C";
          console.log(newTempUnit);
          tempValue = newTempUnit;
          if (newTempUnit == "F") {
            num = Math.round(parseInt(arr.main.temp * (9/5) + 32));
            var fahTemp = num+String.fromCharCode(176)+`<span class=\"temp\" id='ctof'>${tempValue}</span>`;
            $("#temperature").html(fahTemp)
          } else {
            $("#temperature").text(temp);
          }
```

For the full code and CSS, etc. The codepen is here: https://codepen.io/chase-hippen/pen/WzqBvj?editors=0011

Comment: Have you tried with .on() method for click event of 'ctof' element?

Comment: Yes I had it like that previously. I believe it may have to be separated out as suggested before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$('#ctof').click(function ()...
```

You attach that click function to the *currently existing* DOM element that has an id of `ctof`. When you create a new node with that same id later, it doesn't automatically pick up that same event listener.

Separate out the function so you can add it in more than one place, and make sure that when you create the new node, you add the listener again.

Here's an edited version of your code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvKVNX?editors=0011

Answer (score 1):

The element with ID `#ctof` is dynamic. Every time when you insert it into `#temperature`, the events (`click`) you've attached to it will go.

Answer (score 0):

If #ctof is being dynamically generated you would need to attach the click handler at the Document level. For instance:

```
$(document).on("click", "#ctof", function() {
    // do your work here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when I add a div with id "ctof" and click it, it works just fine.

```
<div id="ctof">click me to change temp</div>
```

I think your js is fine.

Comment: I'm not trying to change it with a link, I want the link to be dynamically attached to the letter